# Отрисовка контента от конкретной кнопки React

Tags: reactjs

Есть всплывающее окно(PopUp), в нем есть массив кнопок отрисованные через map. С лева, есть контент который должен зависить от вида нажатой кнопки. При нажатии на 3ю кнопку должен быть отрисован контент, При нажатии на 5ю отрисоваться должен совсем другой контент. Как можно это реализовать?
Контент с правой стороны массив.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как связаны данные слева с правойчастью? Самое пеовое, что приходит, это при нажатии слева передавать ИД меню в правый компонент и по нему фильтровать и рендерить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В принципе довольно просто
т.к. весь массив ты перебираешь при помощи map
Создаешь вот такую функцию

```
const [selectedProduct, setIsSelectedProduct] = useState({})
      const handleProductClick = (select) => {
        setIsSelectedProduct(select);
      }
```

т.е. в данном случае select берет нужный объект

затем тебе его надо передать при помощи клика. лучше всего это делать при помощи id
Ниже пример перебора массива как передать данную функцию

```
    {products.map((item) =>
          <button onClick={() => handleProductClick(item.id)} 
          </button>
          </div>
    )}
```

ну а затем все вывести вот так

```
{products.map((item) => {
    if (selectedProduct === item.id) {
  return (
    <p>{item.title}</p>
  )
}
```